# RichTextFX StyleClassedTextArea padding

Tags: css, javafx, richtextfx

I am using StyleClassedTextArea like a textbox with styles in my app

However the text inside StyleClassedTextArea doesn't appear to be properly padded on all sides like it does in the textbox

StyleClassedTextArea
[image]

Textbox:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
.styled-text-area .paragraph-box:first-paragraph .paragraph-text {
    -fx-padding: 10 10 10 10;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: I think you mean `TextField` and not `TextBox`. The names of elements must be accurate .

Answer (score 0):

Please try this;

```
.styled-text-area .content {
    -fx-padding: 10.0 10.0 10.0 10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
.styled-text-area .paragraph-box:first-paragraph:last-paragraph .paragraph-text {
    -fx-padding: 5 8;
}
```

Give more height to StyleClassedTextArea, and try different values for padding.